# C# intellisense incorrect for method that takes a dynamic argument

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamic, intellisense

consider follow simple class

```
public class SomeType
{
    public static int Fn(dynamic arg) { return 1; }            
}
```

and the follow statement

```
dynamic value = 10;
var a = SomeType.Fn(null);
var b = SomeType.Fn(value);
```

the type of a is correct ( int )

the type of b is wrong ( dynamic )

I can't use intellisense any more on b until I do a dummy recast (int)SomeType.Fn(value) for what was already prototype to return an integer.

the question is, why the dynamic in the argument makes the intellisense to change my function prototype signature ?

even if I insert a dynamic into a function, that function cannot return nothing else than what is declared in its prototype, is this a bug ?

current **workaround** for me is the following

```
var b = SomeType.Fn((object)value);
```

Comment: It looks like a bug. Are you using VS2015?

Comment: It does not change type of b, it still `int` (use `b.GetType()`), maybe the bug on intellisense?

Comment: Doesn't look like an Intellisense bug at all to me. The Intellisense behaviour matches the compiler's behaviour, does it not?

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to check whether this is an Intellisense bug: call a method that is not available for `int`. If the compiler gives the variable the type `int`, you'll get a compile-time error. If the compiler gives the variable the type `dynamic`, you'll get a run-time error.

```
dynamic value = 10;
var a = SomeType.Fn(null);
a.DoesNotExist();
var b = SomeType.Fn(value);
b.DoesNotExist();
```

If you try this, you'll find that only `a.DoesNotExist()` causes a compile-time error.

In other words, the Intellisense behaviour you're seeing perfectly matches the compiler's behaviour, which is that a method call involving `dynamic` arguments has a `dynamic` result.

Your workaround isn't a workaround, it's a fix. When you have `dynamic` types, you're asking the compiler to ensure the expression is resolved at run-time. When you cast to `object`, you're taking the `dynamic` types out, and at that point the compiler will fully resolve the expression at compile-time again.