# Why do I have to explicitly type a local variable?

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic, var

In this example I had to explicitly declare the variable as IDictionary<string, string> instead of var but I don't understand why.

Can someone explain why when I originally declared it as `var` the Visual Studio tooltip indicated it was `dynamic` even though DictionaryHelper.ParseOptional() returns an IDictionary<string, string>?

ParseOptional is declared as:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> ParseOptional(dynamic json, string variableName);
```

The mergeVariables parameter is coming from Json.Decode(), hence the dynamic variable.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, .NET v4.7.2, C#7.3 in case it's relevant.

```
private static ICollection<IMergeVariable> ParseMergeVariables(dynamic mergeVariables)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> mergeDictionary = DictionaryHelper.ParseOptional(mergeVariables, "mergeVariables");

    return mergeDictionary?.Select(variable => new MergeVariable(variable.Key, variable.Value)).Cast<IMergeVariable>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: why don't you deserialise your json directly to your target data type?

Comment: It's because `mergeVariables` is `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic):

> The result of most dynamic operations is itself dynamic.

I believe this is because the types are resolved at runtime (hence "dynamic" typing).

Related:

- [Why does a method invocation expression have type dynamic even when there is only one possible return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9382130/9287029)
- [Why the deduced return type of a method with a ExpandoObject parameter is always dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54019029/9287029)
- [C# intellisense incorrect for method that takes a dynamic argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39551475/9287029)

Edit: I believe this case is covered by [ECMA-334 C# Language Specification 5th Edition (December 2017)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf), Section 12.7.6 Invocation expressions, subsection 12.7.6.1 General, which states that:

> An invocation-expression is dynamically bound (§12.3.3) if at least one of the following holds:
>
> •The primary-expression has compile-time type dynamic.
>
> •At least one argument of the optional argument-list has compile-time type dynamic
>
> In this case, the compiler classifies the invocation-expression as a value of type dynamic.